# php and saving data sent to it to a file

Tags: php

I have a file on my webserver called photo.php and this is eluding me.
i have a program written in c++ that sends pictures to photo.php. how do i save this data back to a image?

this is the raw data from fiddler 4

```
POST http://osxchange.org/share/photo.php HTTP/1.1
Host: osxchange.org
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------0123abcdefab
X-SecondLife-UDP-Listen-Port: 60424
Content-Length: 55506

------------------------------0123abcdefab
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="caption"


------------------------------0123abcdefab
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="snapshot.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpg
     JFIF         C             



 $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342   C         


2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222   X "
```

the client program show that it is adding the image to the body being sent to photo.php if that makes any difference.

i have also tried saving everything sent as GET POST PUT REQUEST, the file shows no data in it even tho fiddler show it being sent.

this is the code from the client dealing with photo uploads

```
std::string imageFormat;
    if (dynamic_cast<LLImagePNG*>(image.get()))
    {
        imageFormat = "png";
    }
    else if (dynamic_cast<LLImageJPEG*>(image.get()))
    {
        imageFormat = "jpg";
    }
    else
    {
        LL_WARNS() << "Image to upload is not a PNG or JPEG" << LL_ENDL;
        return;
    }

    // All this code is mostly copied from LLWebProfile::post()
    const std::string boundary = "----------------------------0123abcdefab";

    LLSD headers;
    headers["Content-Type"] = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;

    std::ostringstream body;

    // *NOTE: The order seems to matter.
    body    << "--" << boundary << "\r\n"
            << "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"caption\"\r\n\r\n"
            << caption << "\r\n";

    body    << "--" << boundary << "\r\n"
            << "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"snapshot." << imageFormat << "\"\r\n"
            << "Content-Type: image/" << imageFormat << "\r\n\r\n";

    // Insert the image data.
    // *FIX: Treating this as a string will probably screw it up ...
    U8* image_data = image->getData();
    for (S32 i = 0; i < image->getDataSize(); ++i)
    {
        body << image_data[i];
    }

    body << "\r\n--" << boundary << "--\r\n";

    // postRaw() takes ownership of the buffer and releases it later.
    size_t size = body.str().size();
    U8 *data = new U8[size];
    memcpy(data, body.str().data(), size);

    // Note: we can use that route for different publish action. We should be able to use the same responder.
    LLHTTPClient::postRaw("http://osxchange.org/share/photo.php", data, size, new LLFacebookShareResponder(), headers);
}
```

Comment: Without seeing any of your code it is going to be very hard for anybody to help you.

Comment: Start by looking at the contents of the `$_FILES['image']` variable

Comment: just made edit to include client code.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will be a good start:

```
if (isset($_FILES['image'])) {
    $savePath = './uploads/';
    $oldName = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $newName = $savePath.$_FILES['image']['name'];

    move_uploaded_file($oldName, $newName);
}
```